# I got the below data from server and duplicated data showing in Name. I don't want duplicate data. can u help to solve this

Tags: react-native

I am working on `React Native`
I got the below data from server and duplicated data showing in Name

> (Name: "HospitalOne", Name: "HospitalTwo", Name: "HospitalOne",).
> I don't want duplicate data.
> can u Help to solve this.

> 0: {Id: 1, Name: "HospitalOne", MobileNumber: "0000000100", Email: "sivachandra.k@gmail.com", Status: "active", …}
> 1: {Id: 2, Name: "HospitalTwo", MobileNumber: "0000000101", Email: "skadari@viswgnabharathi.com", Status: "active", …}
> 2: {Id: 3, Name: "HospitalThree", MobileNumber: "0000000103", Email: "valladi@vbbsolutions.com", Status: "active", …}
> 3: {Id: 4, Name: "HospitalOne", MobileNumber: "9885751550", Email: "chandunimsha@gmail.com", Status: "active", …}
> 4: {Id: 6, Name: "NMK",          MobileNumber: "1111111", Email: "murali.naripeddi@aikiasolution.com", Status: "active", …}
> 5: {Id: 7, Name: "HospitalFive", MobileNumber: "0000000104", Email: "HospitalFour@gmail.com", Status: "inactive", …}
> 6: {Id: 8, Name: "HospitalFive", MobileNumber: "0000000105", Email: "mytvglp@gmail.com", Status: "active", …}

I need output as per below. duplicates has to removed.

> 0: {Id: 1, Name: "HospitalOne", MobileNumber: "0000000100", Email: "sivachandra.k@gmail.com", Status: "active", …}
> 1: {Id: 2, Name: "HospitalTwo", MobileNumber: "0000000101", Email: "skadari@viswgnabharathi.com", Status: "active", …}
> 2: {Id: 3, Name: "HospitalThree", MobileNumber: "0000000103", Email: "valladi@vbbsolutions.com", Status: "active", …}
> 3: {Id: 6, Name: "NMK",          MobileNumber: "1111111", Email: "murali.naripeddi@aikiasolution.com", Status: "active", …}
> 4: {Id: 7, Name: "HospitalFive", MobileNumber: "0000000104", Email: "HospitalFour@gmail.com", Status: "inactive", …}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
var a = [{'name':'bob', 'age':22}, {'name':'alice', 'age':12}];     

var unique = a.filter((set => f => !set.has(f.name) && set.add(f.name))(new Set));

console.log(unique);
```

Comment: i have only one array bro, duplicate data in one array.

Comment: i have only one array bro, duplicate data in one array.

var data= [
0: {Id: 1, Name: "HospitalOne"}
1: {Id: 2, Name: "HospitalTwo"}
2: {Id: 3, Name: "HospitalThree"}
3: {Id: 4, Name: "HospitalOne"}
4: {Id: 6, Name: "NMK"}
5: {Id: 7, Name: "HospitalFive"}
6: {Id: 8, Name: "HospitalFive"}
]
If you observe above array index[0] and Index[3] hospital names are same. so i want to remove duplicate hospital name
var data= [
0: {Id: 1, Name: "HospitalOne"}
1: {Id: 2, Name: "HospitalTwo"}
2: {Id: 3, Name: "HospitalThree"}
3: {Id: 6, Name: "NMK"}
4: {Id: 7, Name: "HospitalFive"}]

Comment: I have updated my answer you can check https://jsfiddle.net/h1239ag4/